# $_COOKIE[] will not accept string with periods?

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
  $Test = "dsdsdad.dsad";

  if (isset($_COOKIE["$Test"])) {
      echo "I GOT A COOKIE WITH A PERIOD";
  } else {
    setcookie("$Test", "yes", time()+60*60*24*3);
  }

  $Test = "dsdsdaddsad";

  if (isset($_COOKIE["$Test"])) {
      echo "I GOT A COOKIE WITHOUT A PERIOD";
  } else {
    setcookie("$Test", "yes", time()+60*60*24*3);
  }

?>
```

It seems that $_COOKIE[] will not accept anything with a period in it. However, the setcookie function sets both cookies fine. What is the way around this? I'd like it to read a cookie with a dot.

Comment: Please don't use `"$test"`, simply use `$test` instead. That's more nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

So, if you set the cookie `dsdsdad.dsad`, it'll be stored as `dsdsdad_dsad` when PHP parses the cookie headers..